# How to prove that $l^p$ is separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

I want to show that $l^p$ is separable.

I got the hint to use the set $E:=\{e_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where
$e_n$ denotes the sequence with a 1 in the n-th position and else zeros.

There is a corollary that stats that, if there exists a countable subset $A$ in a normed vector space $X$ such that $\overline{span A}=X$, then $X$ is separable.

Thus I want to show that $\overline{span E}=l^p$.

Since $(l^p,\lVert.\rVert_p)$ is a metric space (the norm induces the metric), the closure of $span E$ are all limits of sequences with elements in $span E$.

This means that for some $x=(x_n)$ in $l^p$, I have to construct a sequence $y_n=(y_{1,n},y_{2,n},...)$ such that $y_{i,n} \in spanE$ and $y_n \rightarrow x$.

But I don't know how to construct/find this sequence. (I do not even know if my approach is correct).

Comment: It's a good approach! Let's start here: given an element of $l^p$, how can you tell if it is in $\operatorname{span} E$? In other words, what are the elements of $\operatorname{span} E$?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Well the definition is $span E=\{ \sum \lambda_i e_i: \lambda_i \in K, e_i \in E 
 \}$, thus the Elements of $span E$ are all sequences of the form $(\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n,0,0,...)$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk This would mean that for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...) \in l^p$ the sequence I am looking for is  $(y_{1,n},y_{2,n},...,y_{k,n},...)$ where
$y_{k,n}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,0,...)$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. In fact, the question of separability of $l^p$ is a standard result.